# Add new labels to combo chart

Tags: excel, vba

I run the following to sub to print a line and column combo chart.

```
Sub addchart()

    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim dt As Range
     
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dt = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(i, 11))
    Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(Width:=1300, Height:=300, Left:=Range("a13").Left, Top:=Range("a13").Top).Chart
    
    
    With ch
        .SetSourceData Source:=dt
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Deflection Curve"
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Deflection"
        .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    End With

     If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(i, 10))) > -50 Then
    With ch.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = -50
        .MaximumScale = 0
    End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The second series is basically just two bars that act as markers as shown.

[image]

I want to improve the visibility of these marker columns in any way I can. I tried looking for ways to increase the bar width but it seems that that is a result of gap width and chart size. So now I want to add labels to these bars but the labels are custom.

The series contains hundreds of zero values and two non zero values (as many as the entries in the line chart). I want to label one non zero value as the "minimum" and the other non zero value as, well any arbitrary name. If that isn't possible I'd like to at least display the y values as labels on these columns but only for these columns (ignoring all the zero values). What are my options here?

Comment: There have been other q&a about labels on charts - did you check them for ideas?

Comment: @SolarMike I did find ways to add labels to columns but I can't find much on manually specifying column for a specific entry and ignoring other entries. As for bar width, I found that I read on a thread that I can't change that without changing chart size and gap width. right now I'm expecting the bars to spill over and overlap with the other entries (which is fine because they're all zero). But I'll go through the forum again.

Comment: I have an answer you should check out about linking the chart titles to cells on the sheet.